# Wordpress/PHP: Setting cookie not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to create a cookie in Wordpress if the user came from one of my campaigns. If utm_source equals "fb" or "ob" I want to set a cookie "source = fb or ob", but my code below doesn't seem to work, no cookie is created. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php function strip_next_tags_action () { 
    global $post;
        if ( isset( $_GET['utm_source'] )  or $_GET['utm_source'] == 'fb' or $_GET['utm_source'] == 'ob') {
            setcookie( "source", $_GET['utm_source'], 30 * DAY_IN_SECONDS, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN );
        }
        else {
            $post->post_content = str_replace("<!--nextpage-->", "",
                $post->post_content, $count);
        }
        return $post;
    }
    add_action ('loop_start', 'strip_next_tags_action'); ?>
```

Comment: Is this function running before any output has already been sent? Cookies are part of the HTTP headers so have to be set up before anything is output from the web server.

Comment: The function is at the beginning of the single.php file.

Comment: I tried putting it in function.php but it still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function that affects cookies cannot be at the beginning of the single.php file - there's already output being generated, headers sent, and the opportunity to touch the cookies is gone.

If you look at the [action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) you were using - `loop_start` - you'll see it's *after* other actions that are outputting HTML - so it's too late.

This should be either within a plugin, or in the theme's functions.php file, and must be called on the appropriate [action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) - probably the `wp` action best suits your needs:

In your theme's functions.php file:

```
function strip_next_tags_action () { 
    global $post;
    if ( isset( $_GET['utm_source'] )  or $_GET['utm_source'] == 'fb' or $_GET['utm_source'] == 'ob') {
        setcookie( "source", $_GET['utm_source'], 30 * DAY_IN_SECONDS, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN );
    } else {
        $post->post_content = str_replace("<!--nextpage-->", "",
            $post->post_content, $count);
    }
}

add_action ('wp', 'strip_next_tags_action');
```